# Rails Capybara selenium test on specific browser version and visualize test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using Capybara selenium/webkit in functional testing, I don't really understand how it works behind the scene.

By checking the Capybara document, the selenium by default is using firefox browser for testing. It doesn't even mention what is the version it is using. (I didn't install firefox, I think it came together with the gem `selenium-webdriver` or `capybara-webkit`)

My question:

1) If I want to trigger my test on specific browser version, is it possible? How can I do that? For example, on Chrome browser version 53.1.2.

2) The automated functional test all conducted behind the scene, is it possible to visualize the testing procedure? For example, Selenium driver launch the browser and visualize the click/scroll/drag effect along with the test running?

Comment: I found this website explaining the `webkit` and `selenium` quite clearly, hope it is useful for other people: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/capybara/capybara_with_selenium_and_webkit.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selenium-webdriver gem does not install firefox, and if you're not seeing a browser opening when you run your tests you are not actually using selenium-webdriver, since when used with desktop browsers (firefox, chrome, IE, safari) it will open those browsers and you can watch it interact with the app being tested.

When you run tests Capybara uses the driver identified by `Capybara.current_driver` at the start of each test.  In the normal Capybara configuration (when using rspec) the current driver is set in a before block - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.12.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L26 - to either the value of `Capybara.javascript_driver` or `Capybara.default_driver` depending on whether the test has a `js: true` metadata tag or not - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.12.0/README.md#drivers and https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.12.0/README.md#using-capybara-with-rspec .

By default `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium` and the default config for that driver would use firefox.  Therefore if you add the `js: true` metadata to one of your tests it will use the selenium driver and attempt to run your system installed firefox (depending on versions installed you may also need to install geckodriver), raising errors if there is no FF installed. You will also want to read about database_cleaner in the Capybara README and get that installed correctly for testing.  If you don't specify the `js: true` metadata then (by default) your test is using the rack_test driver which does not process CSS or JS and is really only useful for very basic form and link processing testing.  If you want all your tests to run with selenium you could set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` which will then be used for all the tests (you will still need to set up database_cleaner)

The Capybara README has instructions for how to configure the :selenium driver to use Chrome if wanted (you will also need to install chromedriver), and the selenium-webdriver documentation will have details on how you can specify alternate instances of the browsers (if you have multiple versions installed).

If on the other hand you want to use the capybara-webkit gem (or Poltergeist) you would need to specify the name of the registered driver - for instance `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit/:poltergeist` - see their READMEs for details of the different options you can specify for each of those drivers when registering them.

Comment: yes! now I know where I was confused, I saw `selenium-webdriver` in my gem file, I thought I am using it, but in fact, I am not using selenium, I am actually using `capybara-webkit`, that's why no browser was launched along with my test.

Comment: @GMsoF capybara-webkit and poltergeist are both headless drivers so with those there is no way to watch the running test.  They are also both relatively behind in the web techs they support (no ES5+ support for instance, although Poltergeist with PhantomJS 2.5 when stable should be more up to date).  If the answer was complete enough for you don't forget to accept it (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.